# How can I update table from another SQL service instance

Tags: sql-server, auto-update

I want to link two SQL server instance to update clients tables if the server tables has changed (insert or update). I want the work automatically by SQL Server, I read about [Linked Servers (Database Engine)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) in MSDN.

Does this method do what I want, or is there another way to do it?

**Edit :**

I want to update Data of the tables

Comment: If you have access to the server, then you could do log shipping and or even look at availability groups if you have enterprise.  You can also look at auditing on tables.  Lot of options - what you looking to do?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne I want an autoupdate for client databsa if server tables changed (not all of the tables)

Comment: We do the same, but only notify.  Linked server, interrogate sys.tables and sys.columns, etc. but only notify someone that things have changed - not update.

Comment: Why not use [replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne I edit my question (I want the update of the data not structure)

Comment: I would go with Benjamin's option.  The replication will "lock" the source database, which is likely what you DON'T want.   Be careful with the triggers and check that the linked server is up - otherwise you will/may have rollbacks, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do so is via a trigger on the master table like so:

```
use masterdatabase;
go

create trigger update_clients_of_master 
on dbo.mastertable 
after  update as
begin
update   cl1
set cl1.col1 = i1.col1, cl1.col2=i1.col2 
    from inserted i1
        inner join clientdbname.dbo.clienttable  cl1 on cl1.id=i1.id

end
```

If you cannot create a linked server you can use transactional replication to keep tables in sync but triggers are probably easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Microsoft sync framework here is documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608.aspx
or use replication

Answer (score 0):

You can use replication which allows you to publish one object (one table for example) or more to another server and it will automatically updates the clients table(s) when the source is changed (by insert or update). 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx